# Installing OpenCV 3.0.0 with Eclipse on Windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to install OpenCV version 3.0.0 to be used with Eclipse C++. However, I'm having immense difficulty because old guides aren't compatible since the package file directory has been changed. I can't seem, by any measure, to run any OpenCV programs on the Eclipse C++ IDE without errors related to OpenCV's installation. The documentation on their site is out of date and provided absolutely no help. How in the world do I get OpenCV v3.0.0 to work with my Eclipse C++ IDE? I'm using the MinGW GCC toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to build the opencv libs first, using cmake.

specify your c and c++ compiler, and the make tool, similar to this:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="D:/Programme/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe" -DWITH_IPP=OFF  ..
```

then run:

```
mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make.exe install
```